# Check if a web server is https certificated or not?

Tags: objective-c, nsurlrequest

does annyone knows how i can check if a web server if certificated or not.
in my code im using this:

```
[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[[NSURL URLWithString: urlAddress] host]];
```

But this accepts all the certificates.. but i wanna know if a web server is certificated or not..
if its not then i want to allow it
so im basicly looking for an IF statement

Ty already,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious answer would be not to use that method (which is undocumented and therefore technically out of bounds anyway).

The proper way to handle communication to a site with a self signed certificate is for the user to install the certificate and explicitly set its trust settings.

Answer (score 0):

there is sample application in dev center about using certificates

Comment: could you parse me the link for that? ty,